# Trouble setting a Parameter

Tags: java, validation

Im confused as to how I allow only numbers 1-4? Im not sure if there is a term for this, i think its parameter

**THE CODE IM QUESTIONING IS THE 3RD TO LAST LINE**

```
private void validatePositiveNumber() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: ");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            String input = scanner.next();
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid number.\n", input);
        }
        number = scanner.nextInt();
    } while (number < 4);

    System.out.printf("You have entered a positive number %d.\n", number);
}
```

Comment: Think carefully about what your while condition is saying. Essentially, "keep asking for a valid number WHILE the entered number is less than 4". Is that what you really want?

Comment: Well i want there to be an error whenever the number isnt between 0 and 4

Comment: I understand that. I'm pointing out that your condition does almost the opposite of that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `while (number > 4 || number < 1);` This disallows anything outside of the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: ");
            while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                String input = scanner.next();
                System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid number.\n", input);
            }
            number = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (number > 4 || number < 1);

        System.out.printf("You have entered a positive number %d.\n", number);
```